# EclipseLink JPA on WebLogic 12c leads to StackOverflowError

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jndi, java-ee-6, weblogic12c

I'm developing on WebLogic 12c (12.1.3.0) with it's delivered EclipseLink 2.5.2.

I configured a connection pool to a PostgreSQL-DB.

When I try to access the `@EJB` (SLSB) which contains the `@PersistenceContext` the WebLogic quits with an **StackOverflowError** while it tries to lookup a JNDI resource. I think it's the JTA datasource of the persistence.xml.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.getContextClassLoader(VersionHelper12.java:185)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.ResourceManager.getFactory(ResourceManager.java:418)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getURLObject(NamingManager.java:592)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getURLContext(NamingManager.java:550)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:339)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ApplicationNamingNode.resolveObject(ApplicationNamingNode.java:169)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.resolveObject(BasicNamingNode.java:886)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:219)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ApplicationNamingNode.lookup(ApplicationNamingNode.java:131)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:253)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:426)
    at weblogic.jndi.factories.java.ReadOnlyContextWrapper.lookup(ReadOnlyContextWrapper.java:45)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ApplicationNamingNode.resolveObject(ApplicationNamingNode.java:170)
[...]
```

Does somebody knows such a behaviour?

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: Is there something in the stack causing some sort of recursion?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror for what a stack overflow is, as you haven't provided enough info to show there is anything wrong with the code.  Chances are, you just don't have enough memory allocated to the JVM running WebLogic

Comment: Thanks Chris for your comment. I solved the StackOverflowError. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by increase the debug output of the Webogic server.
There I realized a wrong JNDI adress for the JDBC lookup.
It seems the persistence context tried to use the `non-jta-data-source` instead of the `jta-data-source` of the `persistence.xml`. They were different due to unit testing purpose.
I removed the entry and now the initialization of the JPA contexts works.

Comment: if a normal error causes a StackOverflowError in your server, you have other resource based issues to deal with as well.